# The picture is distorted and deformed after using opencv to zoom the picture in pyqt5

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

Purpose: I first use opencv to get the first frame (picture) of the imported video, and then according to the height and width of the video, I use the resize function of opencv to zoom the picture and display it in QLabel. For example, if the height of the picture is greater than the width, I scale the height of the picture to the height of the QLabel and calculate it according to the aspect ratio of the original picture Get the scaled width value.

Problem: Some pictures can be scaled normally without distortion, but other pictures will be distorted.

I inherited the UI file from the file where the logic of scaling the picture is located.
This is the UI file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 750)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(MainWindow.width(),MainWindow.height())
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.mainBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainBox.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 0)
        self.mainBox.setObjectName("mainBox")
        self.topBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.topBox.setObjectName("topBox")
        self.openFileBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.openFileBtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 40))
        self.openFileBtn.setObjectName("openFileBtn")
        self.topBox.addWidget(self.openFileBtn)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40,20,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.topBox.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.mainBox.addLayout(self.topBox)
        self.midBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.midBox.setObjectName("midBox")
        self.viewArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.viewArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.viewArea.setObjectName("viewArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,972,575)self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.viewData = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.viewData.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 976, 620))
        self.viewData.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(976, 620))
        self.viewData.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.viewData.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.viewData.setObjectName("viewData")
        self.viewArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.midBox.addWidget(self.viewArea)
        self.mainBox.addLayout(self.midBox)
        self.startDetectBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.startDetectBtn.setObjectName("startDetectBtn")
        self.mainBox.addWidget(self.startDetectBtn)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.mainBox.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        self.bottomBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.bottomBox.setObjectName("bottomBox")
        self.mainBox.addLayout(self.bottomBox)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.mainBox)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "XXX"))
        self.openFileBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "匯入影片"))
        self.viewData.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "請選擇影片"))
        self.startDetectBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "偵測並儲存結果"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and then this is the code snippet of the logic to scale the image:

```
from posixpath import dirname
import sys
import os
from collections import deque
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, Qt , pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from UIwindow import  Ui_MainWindow

class Logic_MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow,QDialog):
    global openfile_name_video
    global save_name_video
    global temp_video
    viewWidth = 0
    viewHeight = 0
    isDetect = False
    send_signal_hint = pyqtSignal()
    dirname,_ = os.path.split(__file__)

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(Logic_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.openFileBtn.clicked.connect(self.open_video) 
    self.startDetectBtn.clicked.connect(self.btn_detect)
    self.send_signal_hint.connect(self.finish_hint)
    self.progressBar.setMinimum(0)
    self.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
    self.progressBar.setValue(0)
    self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color:#878787")
    self.openFileBtn.setStyleSheet("border-width: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;color:#FFFFFF ")
    self.openFileBtn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Microsoft JhengHei"))
    self.startDetectBtn.setStyleSheet("border-width: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color:#FFFFFF;color:#FFFFFF;padding: 5px;")
    self.startDetectBtn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Microsoft JhengHei"))
    self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("color:#FFFFFF")
    self.progressBar.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Microsoft JhengHei"))
    self.viewData.setStyleSheet("background-color:#000000")
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.dirname+'/img/bg.png')
    self.viewData.setPixmap(pixmap)
    global openfile_name_video,temp_video
    openfile_name_video = ''
    temp_video = ''

def open_video(self):
    global openfile_name_video,temp_video
    openfile_name_video, _ =QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.openFileBtn,'選擇要偵測的影片',os.getcwd(),'"mp4 Files (*.mp4);;avi Files (*.avi)"')
    if openfile_name_video != '': #If a video is selected, save the selected video to the variable of the temporary video
        temp_video = openfile_name_video
    elif openfile_name_video == '': #If no video is selected, save the last selected video to the openfile_name_video variable
        openfile_name_video = temp_video
    self.getFirstFrame(openfile_name_video) #Pass the selected video into the getFirstFrame method

def getFirstFrame(self,video):
    global viewWidth
    global viewHeight
    viewWidth = self.viewData.width() #Get the width of QLabel
    viewHeight = self.viewData.height() #Get the height of QLabel
    if video != "": #If the incoming video is received, perform the following actions
        vid = cv.VideoCapture(video) #Use VideoCapture to create a VideoCapture object for the video
        ret, self.frame = vid.read() #Get the first frame of the video
        frame = cv.cvtColor(self.frame,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height,width = frame.shape[:2] #This line of description starts to perform the action of scaling the first frame of the movie
        if height > width: #If the height of the first frame of the video is greater than the width, perform the following actions
            frame = cv.resize(frame, (int(width/height*viewHeight), viewHeight),cv.INTER_LINEAR) #Scale the height of the first frame of the video to the height of the QLabel, and scale the width of the first frame of the video according to the aspect ratio of the original frame
        else: #If the width of the first frame of the video is greater than the height, perform the following actions
            frame = cv.resize(frame, (viewWidth, int(height/width*viewWidth)),cv.INTER_LINEAR) #Scale the width of the first frame of the movie to the width of the QLabel, and scale the height of the first frame of the movie according to the aspect ratio of the original frame
        Qframe = QtGui.QImage(frame.data,frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0],QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888) #Create a QImage object for the zoomed image
        self.viewData.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(Qframe)) #Place QImage into QLabel
```

This is the first video I used to test the first frame of the scale:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18WLyHr0mKo5E2_dgRB3GYq6BE7vqf_aO/view?usp=sharing

This is the result image corresponding to the first frame of the first video I used to test scale:
[image]

Then this is the second video I used to scale the first frame of the video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gbTDv2Fe-_YyKRRfBrLfW5iFXtYBgqub/view?usp=sharing

This is the result of the second video I used to scale the first frame of the video:
[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc,
Hello, I have modified the text description of the purpose

Comment: That is not an MRE

Comment: probably an issue with passing the data to Qt. use `cv::imwrite()` and check that the data looks correct when written to a file like that.

Comment: @eyllanesc,I have sorted out the questions, is this MRE?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz,
Hello, thank you for your feedback, I will try your suggestions

Comment: I see nothing in the code that would "zoom". please point out what parts of the code need to be active to cause the issue.

Comment: @YanMing Is scale and zoom the same for you?

Comment: @YanMing A MRE should be *both* minimal (only imports that are required, and the UI should only contain elements that are important for the problem) and reproducible (where is the zoom function? what are the properties of the images that show that behavior?). Also, when using the multiple inheritance to load a Designer UI, you should only use the *proper* base classes: that UI is made with a QMainWindow, so it should only inherit from `QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow`, remove QDialog from there because it's completely wrong (you cannot subclass from *both* QMainWindow *and* QDialog).

Comment: @YanMing Finally, please ensure that you properly [formatting your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) by checking the post preview, as your example has lots of indentation problems. We should be able to copy, paste and run examples possibly without any substantial modification.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz,Hello, sorry, I have annotated the code

Comment: @eyllanesc,
Hello, sorry, my English is not good, I later found out that my scale is scale

Comment: @YanMing I don't see any correspondence between the images, in the first image there is no car and in the second there is (at least there is a part), does that code reproduce that? Not for me.

Comment: @musicamante,Hello, sorry, I roughly understand the meaning of MRE, thank you for your explanation. When I indented the code in the UI file, I found that there are two lines of code that cannot be indented, please forgive me.

Comment: @eyllanesc,Sorry, I have updated the destination text and uploaded two cloud links for test videos

Comment: the `cv.resize` calls will not cause this issue. something else must be going on. can anyone reproduce this? the effect we see must be caused by an off-by-one error in the *interpretation* of the data (width of the picture) vs how much data (how many columns) is really there. potentially, if there is any rounding to *even numbers*, this could happen. or if there is padding/alignment in the data that isn't respected by whatever reads the data (Qt).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz,I tried to calculate the aspect ratio of the first frame of the zoomed video and the aspect ratio of the original video, and their results are very close

Comment: @musicamante,Since my project uses the function of QDialog, it is not deleted

Comment: @YanMing still, subclassing like that is *highly* discouraged, as those classes have different implementations and method overridings that could cause unexpected behavior (and potential crash). By looking at your UI, you don't need a QMainWindow at all, since you're not using any of its features (menu bar, status bar, tool bars, dock widgets), so if you need the features of QDialog (window modality, the `exec()` loop, etc.), then just use a QDialog: create a dialog in Designer and use that in your program, don't try to "mix things" in the wrong way.

Comment: @eyllanesc,Later, when I searched for related issues, I found your comment on a question that was raised in April 2019. I tried your method and the problem was solved successfully. Thank you.